# XSLT to check if a sibling node is a certain element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to use a variable in a template to get the sibling of an ancestor and then if that sibling is a certain element, I want to do something.

I'm able to grab the sibling correctly, but when I use an if to check if the node is the element I want, it never gets hit. What is wrong with my if that it doesn't ever find when the sibling element is 'desiredElement'?

```
<xsl:template match="deltaxml:text[@deltaxml:deltaV2='A']">
    <xsl:variable name="nextVal" select="ancestor::*:textGroup/following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    <xsl:if test="$nextVal = 'desiredElement'">
         <!-- do something -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:if test="$nextVal/self::desiredElement">` or if that element is in that same namespace as the other than `<xsl:if test="$nextVal/self::deltaxml:desiredElement">`. You could also compare `local-name($nextVal) = 'desiredElement'` if you want a string comparison of the element name. Your current attempt compares the string value/contents of the element to the string `desiredElement`.